# SSRS 2008 R2 - Disable Initial Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Sorry if this has been answered before; couldn't find anything specific, or I'm just missing something!

No matter what amalgamation of security settings I use in the .config file, whenever I open up the website to access my specific report (//servername/ReportServer/) it always first tries to authenticate with the user currently logged in to Windows.  This is a validated Controls system so one user will always be logged into the affected computer(s) at all times, thus I need a way to force them to log in when they open the report.  Is this still an Internet Explorer setting like I keep hearing about?

What's my next step?

edit: That may not have been clear.  I'm using a single user to stay logged in to all computers at all times.  I need to publish the username that opened the report ON the report for validation reasons.

more edit: Can't post solution. Noob.  SO!

***PARTIAL SOLUTION! :(***

Of course I solve it 30 seconds after posting the question.  Geez.

Internet Explorer -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet (in my case) -> Custom Level -> (scroll down) User Authentication -> Logon -> Prompt for user name and password BUBBLE.

And woot.

Comment: Ok, not fixed yet.  I have embedded an activex internet explorer browser into my application and can run the report fine.  The first time I show the browser it asks for the username and password, but it never asks for it again unless I restart my application (unacceptable).  Any settings in IE I can use?

Comment: MORE SOLUTION!  Navigating to this link in your browser window: javascript:void(document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache')); will cause ALL credentials in iexplore to be dropped without closing the browser.  WOOT.